# Where to find a jQuery Logo Carousel/Showcase/Sushibar Slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, carousel

I'm searching for a jQuery Logo "Sushibar" Slider like this one http://www.alchemythemes.com/logo-carousel-jquery-logos-showcase/ (example on the right) but I need one hosted on github, so I can use bower to update it.
I would appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would just need to use a carousel plugin like [CarouFredSel](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel) and set it to pause on hover. The example they provide does just that.

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        items               : 2,
        direction           : "up",
        scroll : {
            items           : 1,
            easing          : "elastic",
            duration        : 1000,                         
            pauseOnHover    : true
        }                   
    });
});
```

It is pretty robust.

Also if you want it to fade in like it does in your example you would need a little CSS that toggles Opacity like:

```
.item {opacity:0.5}
.item:hover {opacity:1}
```

Hope that helps.